# Laravel 7 FormRequest update without readonly field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a model that you can't modify some data after creation. With this in mind, when I update, I don't validate theses fields either I don't refer to them in the update method.

The problem is that if I use `->update()` it's not working at all, nothing get committed to the database, and I use `->save()` it fire `INSERT INTO` instead of a `UPDATE`.

I don't understand exactly what's happening. Thank you.

**Model**

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    use Userstamps;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'street_address',
        'street_address2',
        'city',
        'province',
        'postal_code',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'url',
        'description',
        'logo_path',
    ];

    protected $guarded = [
        'active',
        'created_by',
        'modified_by',
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canModify ()
    {
        return ((auth()->user()->role === 'admin') || ($this->created_by === auth()->user()->id));
    }

}
```

**FormRequest**

```
class UpdateProfile extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules ()
    {
        $rules = [
            'name'            => 'required',
            'street_address'  => 'required',
            'street_address2' => 'nullable',
            'city'            => 'required',
            'province'        => 'required',
            'postal_code'     => 'required|regex:/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]( )?\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$/|size:7',
            'phone'           => 'nullable|regex:/^1\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/|size:16',
            'email'           => 'required|email:rfc,dns,spoof|unique:App\User,email',
            'url'             => 'nullable|url',
            'description'     => 'nullable',
            'logo_path'       => 'nullable',
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function update (Profile $profile, UpdateProfile $request)
    {
        if (!$profile->canModify()) {
            return redirect('profiles')
                ->with('error.message', __('app.restricted', [
                    'title' => request("name"),
                ]));
        }

        $update                     = $request->validated();
        $profile['name']            = $update['name'];
        $profile['street_address']  = $update['street_address'];
        $profile['street_address2'] = $update['street_address2'];
        $profile['city']            = $update['city'];
        $profile['province']        = $update['province'];
        $profile['postal_code']     = $update['postal_code'];
        $profile['phone']           = $update['phone'];
        $profile['email']           = $update['email'];
        $profile['url']             = $update['url'];
        $profile['description']     = $update['description'];
        if (isset($update['logo_path'])) {
            $profile['logo_path'] = $request->file('logo_path')->store('uploads/logos');
        }

        $profile->update();

        return redirect()
            ->route('profiles', $profile)
            ->with('saved.message', __('profile.message.edited', [
                'title' => $profile->name,
            ]));
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/profile/{profile}/edit', 'ProfileController@edit')
    ->name('profile.edit')
    ->middleware('auth');

Route::put('/profile/update', 'ProfileController@update')
    ->name('profile.update')
    ->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Can you please share your route call for this?

Comment: I added the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mass Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates)

> The update method expects an array of column and value pairs representing the columns that should be updated.

Since you say "when I update, I don't validate theses fields either I don't refer to them in the update method", you already have that array in the `$update` variable, I think you could just do something like this:

```
public function update (Profile $profile, UpdateProfile $request)
{
    if (!$profile->canModify()) {
        return redirect('profiles')
            ->with('error.message', __('app.restricted', [
                'title' => request("name"),
            ]));
    }

    $update = $request->validated();
    if (isset($update['logo_path'])) {
        $update['logo_path'] = $request->file('logo_path')->store('uploads/logos');
    }

    $profile->update($update);

    return redirect()
        ->route('profiles', $profile)
        ->with('saved.message', __('profile.message.edited', [
            'title' => $profile->name,
        ]));
}
```

Also, you'll need to declare a parameter on your route to use model binding to update the existing record on your controller:

```
Route::put('/profile/{profile}/update', 'ProfileController@update')
    ->name('profile.update')
    ->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Thank you, still not working for an unknown reason :(

Comment: Ok, I see, your route doesn't have a parameter, so you can't use model binding on your controller. Can you show us how you send the model id to update? Perhaps it's in the form

Comment: Thank you very much ! It was the route ! I have 6 controllers and it's the only one I forgot lol